# How can I navigate to an anchor in Angular 7

Tags: angular, anchor, routerlink

I've enable the anchorScrolling in routingModule and all the path but when i click on links nothing happened.

'nav-bar.component.html'

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" #sidenav>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeBtn" 
   (click)="closeNav()">&times;</a>
   <a routerLink="/hazyMinds" [fragment]="'HazyMinds'">HazyMinds</a>
   <a routerLink="/ourGames" [fragment]="'Games'">Our Games</a>
   <a routerLink="/contact" [fragment]="'Contact'">Contact</a>
</div>
<span id="openNavBtn"  (click)="openNav()" #openBtn>&#9776;</span>
```

'app.component.html'

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<app-hazy-minds id="HazyMinds"></app-hazy-minds>
<app-games id="Games" ></app-games>
<app-contact id="Contact"></app-contact>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

'app-routing.module.ts'

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {ContactComponent} from './contact/contact.component';
import {GamesComponent} from './games/games.component';
import {HazyMindsComponent} from './hazy-minds/hazy-minds.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'hazyMinds', component : HazyMindsComponent},
  {path: 'ourGames', component : GamesComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component : ContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      scrollOffset: [0, 64]
    }),
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})


export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I expect that when i clicked on link it automatically scroll to the correct anchor.
Someone know what's wrong with my code? thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can use fragments for this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/results'], { fragment: 'top' });
```

//

```
<h1 id="top">asdasd</h1>
```

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: it should be <h1 id="top"> not fragment

Answer (score 7):

For me, other solutions worked OK for initial navigation but no matter what I tried, I could not get the anchor scrolling to work with navigation history.

In other words, when I went "back" or "forward" in my browser, the URL would update but I could not get Angular to scroll to the proper place.  From logging, it seems that Angular was not actually acknowledging the fragment when going back/forward and so the scrolling was not being triggered.

I decided to subscribe to the URL and manually scroll when a fragment is found:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
    if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      let fragmentIdx = val.urlAfterRedirects.lastIndexOf('#');
      if (fragmentIdx >= 0 && fragmentIdx < val.urlAfterRedirects.length - 1) {
        let fragment = val.urlAfterRedirects.substring(fragmentIdx+1);
        console.log('fragment: ' + fragment);
        document.getElementById(fragment).scrollIntoView();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

In this approach I'm using `document.getElementId` to lookup an element to scroll into view.  So, in this approach the URL `fragment` is also the element `id`.  This is easily modified if you want to avoid using `id`'s and instead look up elements by CSS class or otherwise.

Finally, I changed the settings in the main app module back to defaults with regards to scrolling, etc.  This manual approach requires no non-default settings.

Now, I can visit different anchors and see the scrolling as I go back/forward in history.  Hope it helps someone!

**EDIT:**

In order to reuse this snippet with multiple components I refactored this into its own service.  This service has a single method that I call from the `ngOnInit` of any page/component where I want anchor scrolling.

Here's a sample service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'any'
})
export class AnchorScrollService {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  listen(): Subscription {
    return this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
      // console.log(val);
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let fragmentIdx = val.urlAfterRedirects.lastIndexOf('#');
        if (fragmentIdx >= 0 && fragmentIdx < val.urlAfterRedirects.length - 1) {
          let fragment = val.urlAfterRedirects.substring(fragmentIdx+1);
          // console.log('fragment: ' + fragment);
          document.getElementById(fragment).scrollIntoView();
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Note: the latest Chrome has a bug with anchor scrolling that I'm seeing on initial navigation.  Subsequent navigation/history works and all is perfect in, say, Firefox.  Worth noting though in case you are having Chrome frustrations...you're not alone!

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this, I was struggling with the same exact problem, and your answer worked perfectly for me :)